# First Data Global Gateway API 1.1 and doing a postauth. Invalid XML

Tags: credit-card, merchant-account

I'm trying to complete a postauth on this api, and I keep getting invalid xml.  The documentation does not have the format for a post auth in it.

Here is what I'm sending

```
<order>
<payment>
<chargetotal>.80</chargetotal>
</payment>
<orderoptions>
<result>LIVE</result>
<ordertype>POSTAUTH</ordertype>
<oid>40FAEB4A-57B1EFCC-666-1340B8</oid>
<tdate>1471279052</tdate>
</orderoptions>
<transactiondetails>
<transactionorigin>RETAIL</transactionorigin>
<terminaltype>POS</terminaltype>
</transactiondetails>
<merchantinfo>
<configfile>1001343551</configfile>
</merchantinfo>
</order>
```

Response:  Invalid XML

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this is the proper format:

```
<order>
  <merchantinfo>
    <configfile>1909449616</configfile>
  </merchantinfo>
  <orderoptions>
 <ordertype>postauth</ordertype>
  <result>live</result>
 </orderoptions>
  <payment>
<chargetotal>0.80</chargetotal>
 </payment>
<transactiondetails>
   <oid>0AAE1204-57B23716-297-1340B8</oid>
</transactiondetails>
</order>
```

The .80 also caused a problem, I changed it to 0.80 and the new format, and it went through.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, it didn't want to indent properly

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a post auth require an authorization code ?  In my experience people doing post auths without an actual externally acquired auth code run into trouble with their processor eventually.

the post auth way back was used when the teller had to call the processing center for a phone approval.

I'm just curious as to your use case.